# sign in using face id using flutter

Tags: flutter, face-recognition, unlock

im trying find ways to do face unlock using flutter. my idea is to provide IT illiterate user easy sign in method, so for the user name will be voice recognition and the password will be their face. I've searched everywhere but could not find anything. thank you.

Answer (score 4):

[Local Auth](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/local_auth) is a good package for using local authentication. For users with an iPhone X faceId will be used, otherwise it will use touchId.